# How to create scenario for Ultimate Thread group

Tags: graph, jmeter, reporting, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I wish to create scenario for Ultimate Thread group for JMeter for 50 users,  no time dependent constraint here as it's a Tableau based application.

There are total 46 APIs I've gathered from Swagger API documentation.

I've 5 user Id's which generate authorization token

My client also not well versed in Load testing and they are expecting me to design the scenario for Load testing.

I'm also new to JMeter load testing, but I've created jmx script for all 46 API's with single user they all are working with success, and I'm not sure how to create Load scenario with Ultimate Thread group which will be most suitable for my project.

Someone told me using Ultimate Thread Group will be correct approach for creating the scenario, also I am the only tester in my scrum team, so I need to find out all suitable scenarios.

At end I need to share the report to Client, but the report generation done with JMeter is very complex, since I have 46 APIs and 50 users so the graphs are getting very complex, I also need some suggestion what will be the best and simple way to generate simple reports, which I can explain to client as well.

I just created simple JMX script which I think would not be of any use until I create a good Load scenario and can generate a simpler report which will be understandable by me as well as by client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `create a good Load scenario` - there is only one criterion of a "good load scenario" - it must represent real life application usage as close as possible, better with 100% accuracy so hammering all API endpoints sequentially with 50 users is not something you should be doing, you should rather come up with real "user paths" which represent real users (or real applications) making use of your system under test

   Also it's not clear what type of test you're performing as there will be different setup for [Load Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing), [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), [Spike Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing), etc. See [Performance Testing vs. Load Testing vs. Stress Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) article to learn more about different performance testing sub-types and when they need to be applied
2. `generate a simpler report` - if you apply these "user journeys" concept and put them under [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) you will have much less data in charts.

   Also you can use [Filter Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) to get individual charts for individual APIs

   And last but not the least, if you generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) you will get interactive charts where you will be able to turn on and off the data points you are interested/not interested in